# Is there a way of replacing a set of values in a common variable in sql?

Tags: sql, list, replace

I need to replace a set of values, one at a time, when there's a `?` in the query. For example:

```sql
select column1,
       column2
from table1
where column1 in (?, ?, ?)
;
```

set of values:
`2, 5, 9`

**Resulting:**

```sql
select column1,
       column2
from table1
where column1 in (2, 5, 9)
;
```

Comment: Which programming language are you programming in to solve this? What have you tried or researched so far? It is clear what you want to do but it is very unclear **where** and **how** you want to do this. Also where does the *set of values* come from? How is it stored? Please give more background information and show the code where you want to implement this (as well as your attempt).

Comment: hello @Peh! this SQL query (which is in reality around 1000 lines of code and around 10000 values) came up from a Microstrategy report, in which there's a bunch of '?' variables, and at the very end, theres a list of values (as shown in the example). So what I want to do is to replace this set of values in the ? variables in the same order as they appear, using whatever tool to do it. I can replace the values in a certain program and after all values are replaced, just run the query in as a regular SQL script. This is probably an easy set, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Which program are you using for that and which programming language? We can't help you if you can't tell us. Where are you running the sql query in? Please [edit] your question and clarify. • See [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: The query with the ? variables is written in mySQL. But then, the set of values is defined as a separate form, as in a txt document. What I'm thinking is to replace those values using regular expressions in search & replace using notepad++, but can't find the right way to do it. Both the SQL query and the set of values are defined in the same page of the script